# Adding timestamps in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am looking to find a birth_date between a range using timestamp (long value) in neo4j.
Here I am matching the user, with id 10662 . Along with other users, with date_birth  in the range between +3 and -3 years of the u.date_birth

The value of 10800000 is the 3 years in milliseconds, but I am not getting any results, I am sure something is wrong. But not able to locate the problem.

I would appreciate any help.

```
match (u:user {id : "10662"})-[r:has_profile]->(p:profile)  , (u2:user)-[r2:has_profile]->(p2:profile)  where  p.user_id <> p2.user_id  and u2.date_birth >= u.date_birth -toInt(10800000) and u2.date_birth <= u.date_birth + toInt(10800000)  return collect (u2.id) as id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 years in milliseconds (assuming 365 days per year) is actually 94608000000.

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (u:user {id : "10662"})-[r:has_profile]->(p:profile), (u2:user)-[r2:has_profile]->(p2:profile)
WHERE
  p.user_id <> p2.user_id AND
  abs(u2.date_birth - u.date_birth) >= 94608000000
RETURN collect(u2.id) as id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```html
match (u:user {id : "10662"})
 , (u2:user)-[r2:has_profile]->(p2:profile)
 where
 p.user_id <> p2.user_id
 and u2.date_birth >= u.date_birth -94608000000
 and u2.date_birth <= u.date_birth +94608000000
return collect (u2.id) as ids
```

AS You correctly pointed out, there was a problem with the value of 3 years in milliseconds. Thank you!